# Adding data to Web AppBuilder in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I'm trying to use Web AppBuilder in ArcGIS Online to create web application. I can start the Web AppBuilder and everything looks fine. But when I try to add data to the application from my ArcGIS Server or from my existing  webmap on ArcGIS Online, I can't see any data. It looks like the Web AppBuilder is trying to add data but nothing happens?

Any ideas ?